# How to render markdown file to HTML using django?

Tags: python, django, web

I am trying to render a page that written in **markdown** to HTML when clicking a link using Django.

but every time I click on the link the markdown page does not render will

here's my *views.py*:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from . import util

def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })

def search(request, name):
    return render(request, f"{ name }.md")
```

and here's the *urls.py*:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<str:name>", views.search, name="search")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the MARKDOWN to HTML your self, it is the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest converting the file beforehand. If you really need to do it at runtime, you can simply use a package to convert the file to HTML and then point to the rendered file. Pypandoc can achieve this and probably many other python packages